# Unable to locate element inside Ajax Table using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I was trying to write a C# & Selenium automation code to visit a webpage and click some elements to arrive at another webpage. 
So in the process, I am supposed to click a checkbox which is present inside a table, which in turn is present inside an Iframe.
I have checked the page source, and have confirmed that there exists only 1 Iframe.

I tried running the following code and get the following error:

> no such element: Unable to locate element

this is a snippet of the code I've used-

```
 webDriver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.TagName("iframe")));
            webDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(webDriver.FindElement(By.TagName("iframe")));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
           // webDriver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#AjaxTable78962_t1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(1) > input[type=\"checkbox\"]"))));
```

I get the exception on this line:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#AjaxTable78782_t1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(1) > input[type=\"checkbox\"]"))));
```

Comment: That table ID (`AjaxTable78782_t1`) looks like it might be dynamically generated?

Comment: yes it is dynamically generated , I recently noticed that .